# Newsletter Feature Request: Add link to view newsletter on a web page

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

I really like the new newsletter showing top questions, but it would be great to have a link in there to "view this newsletter on the website" so that I could quickly go down the list and open each link in a new tab. I don't use web-based email so I have to keep flipping back and forth between my email client and web browser.

Comment: A version of what you have requested has been implemented: http://stackexchange.com/newsletters

Answer (score 1):

I logged in just to request this exact feature. However I can't find any links in my newsletter email that points to the newsletter page on the site.

For instance, from this week's "Personal Productivity" newsletter, out of 53 links

- 32 are links to questions and tags
- 17 are links to users
- remaining 4 are: subscribe more, unsubscribe this/all and feedback.

Adding links such as https://productivity.stackexchange.com/?tab=week would be great help, for cases like [@Jordan Lev](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/166956/jordan-lev) and me.